# How can I test doExpressCheckout and getExpressCheckoutDetails without paying manually?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

To test my integration with PayPal Express Checkout I'm making API calls in the sandbox. Testing setExpressCheckout is fine, but to properly test doExpressCheckout and getExpressCheckout I need to (manually) pay by navigating to the PayPal url and perform the payment with a sandbox user account before making the API calls. Is there a way to avoid this manual labour? It really prohibits automated testing. Using selenium or other tools for automating the browser is a last resort.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to automate this process.  You would have to go through the flow, and you would have to log in with your test sandbox buyer account and agree to the payment.